# Multiple C wires?

Tags: hvac, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I recently received a wifi enabled thermostat which I thought I could install easily since I saw an unused wire (Blue) which I assumed would be the C wire behind the current thermostat.

[image: old]

When I went to install it, I found out the blue wire isn't actually connected to anything but there is a red wire connected the C terminal which I believe runs out to the ac unit.

[image: furnace wiring]

Can I just connect the blue wire to the C terminal in addition to leaving the red wire or will this short something? Or does this just need to be completely rewired?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be fine connecting the unused blue wire to the `C` terminal in the furnace/air handler.

You'll notice that on the `Y` terminal that there's a yellow wire from the thermostat, and a white wire that presumably goes to the outdoor unit. The red wire connected to the `C` terminal, simply completes the circuit through the outdoor units contactor coil.

The full circuit path for cooling would be as follows:

L1 of transformer secondary -> `R` terminal in furnace -> red wire -> `R` terminal on thermostat -> `Y` terminal on thermostat -> yellow wire -> `Y` terminal in furnace -> white wire -> contactor coil -> red wire -> `C` terminal in furnace -> L2 of transformer secondary.